# How to print out this table correctly HTML/Java web app

Tags: java, html, web-applications, html-table

I am having trouble trying to print a table in HTML so that the items appear in the right place. At the moment I have this. This prints the data in a sort of list so everything is on a separate column.

```
                    <table border=0 width="75%">

                        <%
                                    for (int pos = 0; pos < list.size(); pos++) {
                                        Menu menu = list.getMenuAt(pos);
                        %>

                        <tr>
                          <tr width="80%">
                            <b>Title:</b><br>
                            <b>Dish:</b><br>
                            <b>Description:</b><br>
                            <b>Price:</b><br><br>
                          </tr>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="80%">
                                <%= menu.getTitle()%> <br>
                                <%= menu.getDish()%> <br>
                                <%= menu.getDescription()%> <br>
                                <%= menu.getPrice()%> <br><br>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <%
                                    } // end for
                        %>

                    </table>
```

The menu can will have one title with many dish names, dish descriptions and prices.

Comment: You probably need to provide a bit more information as to what you are expecting the table to look like.

Comment: Please separate data processing  from view? See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/87686/nested-languages-code-smell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why do you have `<br/>` inside the `<td>` element. Your code will separate each filed in something like this:

```
Title:
Dish:
Description:
Price:

text
text
text
text
```

I think your code shuold be like this:

```
<table border=0 width="75%">

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Dish</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<%
            for (int pos = 0; pos < list.size(); pos++) {
                Menu menu = list.getMenuAt(pos);
%>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><%= menu.getTitle()%></td>
        <td><%= menu.getDish()%></td>
        <td><%= menu.getDescription()%></td>
        <td><%= menu.getPrice()%></td>
     </tr>
</tbody>

<%
            } // end for
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a `<tr>` nested inside a `<tr>`. These are table rows. Change those to `<td>` for table cells.

```
<tr>
  <td width="80%">
    <strong>Title:</strong><br/>
    <strong>Dish:</strong><br/>
    <strong>Description:</strong><br/>
    <strong>Price:</strong><br><br/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Also, use `<strong>` from HTML 4 and close the `<br/>` tag, but these are mostly pedantic :)

EDIT:

Looking at your code, I think what you want is a header row and then to do a for loop and fill in each row with a single "menu" item for each object in the for loop. Try this:

```
<table border="0" width="75%">
    <!-- Table header -->
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Title:</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Dish:</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Description:</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Price:</strong></td>
    </tr>

<%
    for (int pos = 0; pos < list.size(); pos++) {
        Menu menu = list.getMenuAt(pos);
%>

    <!-- Table contents -->

    <tr>
        <td><%= menu.getTitle(); %></td>
        <td><%= menu.getDish(); %></td>
        <td><%= menu.getDescription(); %></td>
        <td><%= menu.getPrice(); %></td>
    </tr>

<%
    } // end for
%>

</table>
```

You'll only want the header with "Title", "Dish" etc. once up the top and then run the for loop and add in the rows after that. Notice that each row has the field on a separate cell, which is how you should separate tabulated data. I would recommend styling with CSS, preferably by including an external CSS file.

Comment: And also move the table heading before the for loop start, my guess is that you don't want the heading to be repeated

Comment: Also realised that they didn't have each field to a separate <td> which would misalign everything